# SOLR MoreLikeThis with date field returns Invalid Date String

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

Tested with SOLR 6.6.6 and now with SOLR 7.7.3 we get the following error:

```
  "error":{
"metadata":[
  "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
  "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
"msg":"Invalid Date String:'1604016000000'",
"code":400}}
```

The field type is this:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DatePointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

and the field:

```
<field name="publicationDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

The search itself is:
http://localhost:8091/solr/en/select?fl=id,uuid,referenceNumber,title,publicationDate&mlt=true&mlt.fl=referenceNumber,title,publicationDate&q=id:1282

The dates are correct in our index - we have checked them many times.

Does anyone have an idea what we are doing wrong?

Comment: So the error occurred after you have migrated from Solr 6 to 7? Did you remove and rebuild your core?

Comment: No, we tried it also already with SOLR 6, but there the error is the same.

Comment: We've also removed all of the documents and re-indexed everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MoreLikeThis component doesn't work with dates**

This is an open issue since April 2015.

Please see here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SOLR/issues/SOLR-7351?filter=allopenissues